# Avoid Lambda function Concurrent executions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

I have a lambda function that is being concurrently executed more than once. And this function needs to visit an API that block all frequent visits. If there a way to avoid concurrent executions? Other methods to avoid authentication failures help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [set the concurrency limit](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/) on the function. You can set the limit as low as `1` so that only one instance of the function is ever running at any given time.